# W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObjec

Tags: java, android, json, qjsonobject

I have tried to fix this json program but always have problem in this case, this program can't output data to database and i think the problem is in java mainactivity. But until now I still don't know where the problem is.

this is my ShaperedPrefManager

```java
public class SharedPrefManager {
    //the constants
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "simplifiedcodingsharedpref";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "keyusername";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "keyid";

    private static SharedPrefManager mInstance;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    //method to let the user login
    //this method will store the user data in shared preferences
    public void userLogin(user user) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(KEY_ID, user.getId());
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, user.getUsername());

        editor.apply();
    }

    //this method will checker whether user is already logged in or not
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null) != null;
    }

    //this method will give the logged in user
    public user getUser() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return new user(
                sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_ID, -1),
                sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null)

        );
    }

    //this method will logout the user
    public void logout() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mCtx.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        mCtx.startActivity(new Intent(mCtx, LoginActivity.class));
    }
}
```

this activity main

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.apbProject.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:inputType="text" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Register" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Already Registered?\nLogin Here"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this my mainactivity java

```js
package com.example.apbProject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.registeractivity.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editTextUsername, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //if the user is already logged in we will directly start the profile activity
        if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class));
            return;
        }

        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);



        findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if user pressed on button register
                //here we will register the user to server
                registerUser();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //if user pressed on login
                //we will open the login screen
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void registerUser() {
        final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();

        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();



        //first we will do the validations

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
            editTextUsername.setError("Please enter username");
            editTextUsername.requestFocus();
            return;
        }





        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            editTextPassword.setError("Enter a password");
            editTextPassword.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        //if it passes all the validations

        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            private ProgressBar progressBar;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //creating request handler object
                RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

                //creating request parameters
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);


                //returing the response
                return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(URLs.URL_REGISTER, params);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                //displaying the progress bar while user registers on the server
                progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                //hiding the progressbar after completion
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                try {
                    //converting response to json object

                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                    //if no error in response
                    if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //getting the user from the response
                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                        //creating a new user object
                      user user = new user(
                                userJson.getInt("id"),
                                userJson.getString("username")

                        );

                        //storing the user in shared preferences
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                        //starting the profile activity
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        //executing the async task
        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
        ru.execute();
    }

}
```

and this is my Api.php

```
lang-php
<?php 
 
 require_once 'DbConnect.php';
 
 $response = array();
 
 if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){
 
 switch($_GET['apicall']){
 
 case 'signup':
 if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','password',))){
 $username = $_POST['username']; 

 $password = $_POST['password'];

 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 
 if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
 $response['error'] = true;
 $response['message'] = 'User already registered';
 $stmt->close();
 }else{
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
 
 if($stmt->execute()){
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, id, username FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($userid, $id, $username);
 $stmt->fetch();
 
 $user = array(
 'id'=>$id, 
 'username'=>$username, 
 
 );
 
 $stmt->close();
 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'User registered successfully'; 
 $response['user'] = $user; 
 }
 }
 
 }else{
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available'; 
 }
 
 break; 
 
 case 'login':
 
 if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password'))){
 
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = md5($_POST['password']); 
 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
 $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$username, $password);
 
 $stmt->execute();
 
 $stmt->store_result();
 
 if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
 
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $username);
 $stmt->fetch();
 
 $user = array(
 'id'=>$id, 
 'username'=>$username, 
 
 );
 
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
 $response['user'] = $user; 
 }else{
 $response['error'] = false; 
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
 }
 }
 break; 
 
 default: 
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
 }
 
 }else{
 $response['error'] = true; 
 $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
 }
 
 echo json_encode($response);
 
 function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){
 
 foreach($params as $param){
 if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
 return false; 
 }
 }
 return true; 
 }
 ?>
```

This my error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCymQ.jpg)

Comment: You are trying to parse a string of HTML as JSON, I would say.

Comment: I can't understand it, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: You haven't posted the stack trace of the exception, so it's difficult to be certain, but most likely the POST request made by `RegisterUser` is returning HTML instead of JSON. You could log the string before you try to parse it to see what's happening, or use the debugger.

Comment: So that is where it's happening (by the way, you should copy and paste stack traces instead of posting images)

Comment: i'm sorry dude, this my first time using stack overflow, and i still got stuck with that problem